# mailx change the direction of the mail

Tags: linux, tcsh, mailx

I use mailx to send mails from servers to me. The problem is that it comes as RTL and not LTR.

How can I define it in the command?

here is the command:

```
cat /tmp/monitor.log | mailx -s "Daily status of ${ihostname}" me@example.com
```

Comment: I don't know anything about RTL, so this is a shot in the dark - maybe you could use a special Unicode character in the text that switches the direction? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark

Comment: My mistake. It came as RTL instead of LTR

Answer (score -1):

You can define it as:

cat /tmp/monitor.log | mail -s "Daily status of ${ihostname}" person@email.com otherperson@email.com

Comment: How does this have anything to do with LTR/RTL?